# MAMP htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, mamp, redirect

I'm using a .htaccess file for the first time with MAMP servor, and I'm trying to do something simple : 
I want this link : http://localhost:8888/My_app/ redirect on : http://localhost:8888/My_app/Pages/ .
I did these on .htaccess file, located on /Application/MAMP/htdocs/My_app/ :

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost:8888/My_app/Pages [L,R=301]`

This work, but it simply redirect the user. I want to see the first url http://localhost:8888/My_app/ and not http://localhost:8888/My_app/Pages in my browser, like a 'pointer' on this page, is it possible ?

Thanks !

- Updated -

So it work great with this code :
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://localhost:8888/My_app/Pages/ [L]`

But I have forgotten something in my question, how to do the same for each file in this folder ? If I want http://localhost:8888/My_app/dashboard.php pointed on http://localhost:8888/My_app/Pages/dashboard.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!Pages/).*)$ /Pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks it work great ! But I have forgotten something in my question, how to do the same for each file in this folder ? If I want http://localhost:8888/My_app/dashboard.php pointed on http://localhost:8888/My_app/Pages/dashboard.php ?